# Como hacer un if en linq

Tags: c#, linq

Cómo puedo hacer un `if` dentro de `Linq` por ejemplo tengo el código:

```
lstParentLines = dbContext.Packages.Select(p => new SummaryViewModel
{ 
    Id = p.Id,
    Package = p.Name,
    CurrentTotal = budgMonthDetails.Where(bm => bm.CostCenterId == costCenterId     &&).Sum(bm => (decimal?)bm.Total) ?? 0,
    PreviousForecast = budgMonthDetails
                       .Where(bm => bm.CostCenterId == costCenterId )
                       .Sum(bm => (decimal?)bm.Forecast) ?? 0,
    VarTotalVSFrcst = (decimal?)(budgMonthDetails
                       .Where(bm => bm.CostCenterId == costCenterId)
                       .Sum(bm => (decimal?)bm.Total) ?? 0) /  ((budgMonthDetails.Where(bm => bm.CostCenterId == costCenterId).Sum(bm => bm.Forecast))) ?? 0
}).ToList();
```

Entonces si `bm.Total` es cero que la division sea: `bm.Forecast` entre `bm.Total`

Pero si `bm.Total` es mayor a cero que la division sea: `bm.Total` entre `bm.forecast`

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la sintaxis completa para lambda

```
//...
.Select(x => 
{
    var model = new Model();

    if (<condicion>) 
    {
        model.Total = // Lo que necesites
    }

    return model;
});
```

fíjate que además de el símbolo `=>` también estoy usando `{ }` y `return`.

Los lambda son métodos regulares con el detalle que existe una forma abreviada que es la más utilizada.

```
 x => x * x
```

Equivale a

```
x =>
{
    // aquí puede haber más código
    return x * x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

la sintaxis sería ésta:

```
if (condicionACumplir)
    variable = variable.Where(p => p.At == At);
```

En tu código quedaría algo así:

```
if(bm.Total==0)
   VarTotalVSFrcst = bm.Forecast/bm.Total;

if(bm.Total>0)
   VarTotalVSFrcst = bm.Total/bm.Forecast;
```

[linq](/questions/tagged/linq)[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)